# Extracting a quoted string from a text file, even if the line wraps

Tags: shell, unix, sed

Hi I have a huge file like :

```
Hi This is a file from and the filename= "file1.txt"
Hello find the filename... filename = "the name of this file is too huge and
goes to the next line but enclosed with double quotes.txt"
There is another file with the filename="file2.txt" size 
is "333kb";
```

---

My intended output is the filename strings only, with no linebreaks present, in a pipe-separated string, like the below:

```
file1.txt | the name of this file is too huge and goes to the next line but enclosed with double quotes.txt | file2.txt
```

I used the below sed command but the result is not as expected. It outputs only the filename is in the same line.

```
sed -n 's/^.*filename="\(.*\)".*/\1/p
```

Please help me get this working, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why "using `sed`" as a precondition? Why not let the person answering the question suggest the best tool for the job, even if they happen to think it's `awk`, or native logic in bash, or something else?

Comment: Also, right now, it's not clear which linebreaks in your text are or aren't literal, since the "file contents" are being rendered as wrapped text. Are the `>`s supposed to indicate linebreaks?

Comment: It would also help to quantify "huge" with some actual numbers to allow realistic benchmarking.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know exactly what the line-wrapping rules are with respect to whether `filename` can ever be on a separate line from the following `=`. (Is your test data truly representative in terms of spaces surrounding the `=` being entirely inconsistent?)

Comment: Is it limited to two lines? Could it wrap into three?

Comment: @Beta.. no, it is not limited to 2 lines.. It can wrap up to any number of lines based on the length of the filename.

Comment: But it always has the form `filename[maybe whitespace]=[maybe whitespace]"[filename]"`, is that right?

Comment: Yes, thats right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with this pipeline:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < input | grep -o 'filename *= *"[^"]*"'
```

*to get:*

```
filename= "file1.txt"
filename = "the name of this file is too huge and goes to the next line but enclosed with double quotes.txt"
filename="file2.txt"
```

*clean-up:*

```
tr '\n' ' ' < input | grep -o 'filename *= *"[^"]*"' | sed 's/.*"\([^"]*\)"/\1/'
```

*to get:*

```
file1.txt
the name of this file is too huge and goes to the next line but enclosed with double quotes.txt
file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

WIth GNU awk for multi-char RS and gensub():

```
$ awk -v RS='\\<filename\\s*=\\s*"[^"]+"' -F'"' -v OFS=' | ' '
    RT {$0=gensub(/\s+/," ","g",RT); printf "%s%s", (NR>1?OFS:""), $2}
    END {print ""}
' file
file1.txt | the name of this file is too huge and goes to the next line but enclosed with double quotes.txt | file2.txt
```